# Multiple Column Duplicates : Sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data like:

A1 B1 C1 v1 
A1 B1 C1 v2 
A1 B1 C2 v3 
A1 B2 C1 v4 
A2 B3 C2 v5 ....

I would like to sum all duplicate tuple (A, B, C) but only if all three values are same, that is Ai = Aj, Bi = Bj and Ci = Cj

I would like the result to be in format:

A1 B1 C1 [sum of relevant vs]
...

I know about SUMIF and Pivot function, but so far couldn't get them to work as required.

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: Previous search on stackoverflow reveals solutions for duplication across single column only. If I miss anything in my search, I am sorry and would appreciate the link to relevant thread.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking for. Are you able to attach a screen shot of your spreadsheet with some test data in and another with the outcome you would like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pivot table is the most appropriate solution to me. Put all three columns A, B and C under row labels and put the 4th column under Values. It should automatically sum the values in the 4th column:

[image]

After that, pick Tabular and Repeat items and then Do Not Show Subtotals under PivotTable Design:

[image]

And you will get this:

[image]

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Thanks! (Cannot upvote though due to lack of reputation).
Though I am curious if it is possible with Office 2007, where repeat labels is not available.